# Alarm Clock with 'German Time' Option - in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, youtube, clock, alarm

Paul here. I'm new to JavaScript and trying to build an alarm clock similar to that described in this question:

[Why does my alarmclock script stop working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486428/javascript-alarmclock-script)

Working demo from Whakkee: http://www.obviousmatter.com/testso/hours2.html

However I would like to use dropdown select instead of text input.

(my demo of what I mean by 'dropdown select', this is not a working example)
http://paulodonovan.net/Experiments/JavaScript/rise-and-shine/rise-and-shine_0.2.html

For an experiment I tried substituting 'text input' with 'select with options' but I don't know how to integrate the select:

```
    <html>

<body>
    <div>
        <form name="frm">

<select name="hour">
<option value="00">00</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>  
</select>   
<select name="mins">
<option value="00">00</option>
<option value="01">01</option>
<option value="02">02</option>
<option value="03">03</option>
<option value="04">04</option>
<option value="05">05</option>
<option value="06">06</option>
<option value="07">07</option>
<option value="08">08</option>
<option value="09">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
<option value="24">24</option>
<option value="25">25</option>
<option value="26">26</option>
<option value="27">27</option>
<option value="28">28</option>
<option value="29">29</option>
<option value="30">30</option>
<option value="31">31</option>
<option value="32">32</option>
<option value="33">33</option>
<option value="34">34</option>
<option value="35">35</option>
<option value="36">36</option>
<option value="37">37</option>
<option value="38">38</option>
<option value="39">39</option>
<option value="40">40</option>
<option value="41">41</option>
<option value="42">42</option>
<option value="43">43</option>
<option value="44">44</option>
<option value="45">45</option>
<option value="46">46</option>
<option value="47">47</option>
<option value="48">48</option>
<option value="49">49</option>
<option value="50">50</option>
<option value="51">51</option>
<option value="52">52</option>
<option value="53">53</option>
<option value="54">54</option>
<option value="55">55</option>
<option value="56">56</option>
<option value="57">57</option>
<option value="58">58</option>
<option value="59">59</option>
</select>

            <input type="button" value="Set Alarm" onclick="justonce=1;">
        </form>
        <font color=#660000 size=20 face=Tahoma><span id="hours"></span></font>
    </div>


</body>
</html>




<script type="text/javascript">
obj_hours=document.getElementById("hours");
justonce=0;

function wr_hours()
{
    time=new Date();

    time_min=time.getMinutes();
    time_hours=time.getHours();

    time_wr=((time_hours<10)?"0":"")+time_hours;
    time_wr+=":";
    time_wr+=((time_min<10)?"0":"")+time_min;

    obj_hours.innerHTML=time_wr;

    if (justonce==1 && frm.mins.value==time_min && frm.hour.value==time_hours) {
            alert('Hello. Rise and Shine. :-)');
            justonce=0;
    }
}

setInterval("wr_hours();",1000);
</script>
```

That doesn't work, any thoughts why? Perhaps I need to use index?

I was hoping to personalize this project a bit and also add some other features, e.g.

- Select a Youtube Video to play as alert, from a list of 10 songs and by pasting a url. I found a similar example in terms of features, but the code is very complex to my eyes..: http://onlineclock.net/video/
- 'German time mode' checkbox: '(everything is 10min earlier so you'll never be late.)'

If time permits:
- Checkbox to 'Vintage Style' switching on an alternative CSS style sheet. That could include an analogue alarm clock I can built in CSS.

Of course I would rather understand and will write from scratch, I don't expect anyone to build it for me but any pointers to relevant tutorials or techniques etc. would be much appreciated.

Thanks, Paul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question seems to me, to be

**Part 1**

> How can I get the chosen value from a `<select>`?

The easiest way is to give the `<select>` an *id* attribute, for example

```
<select id="foobar">
    <option value="00">00</option>
    <option value="01">01</option>
</select>
```

Now, in your *JavaScript*, you can access the chosen value using the following code

```
document.getElementById('foobar').value;
```

Remember that an *id* must be **unique** for the whole page.

**Part 2**

> How can I subtract 10 minutes from the time?

The current code you're using doesn't use a [*Date*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object for user's selection nor use *Number* s, it uses *String* s (as `<option>` values). This means that to subtract 10 minutes you'll have to use one (or do something excessively complicated). As you're not using *Date* in this, I'll avoid it in my answer (though you might want to consider learning about it anyway).

To do what you want you'll need to add a couple more steps. In the following, `form_min` and `form_hours` are the user's selected times.

Step 1. Convert minutes and hours to *Number*.

```
form_min   = parseInt(form_min,   10);
form_hours = parseInt(form_hours, 10);
```

Step 2. Subtract 10 minutes

```
form_min = form_min - 10;
```

Step 3. If minutes are negative, subtract 1 hour and add 60 minutes.

```
if (form_min < 0) {
    form_hours = form_hours - 1;
    form_min = form_min + 60;
}
```

Step 4. Convert back to *String*.

```
form_min   = (form_min   < 10 ? "0" : "") + form_min;
form_hours = (form_hours < 10 ? "0" : "") + form_hours;
```

If you work with `.selectedIndex` (60 options starting from 0 for minutes, etc) you can skip Step 1 as you will have the value as a *Number* due to the fact the option value matches the option's index in this context.

Comment: Thanks Paul S, this is really helpful, especially the idea to convert. And part 3 for handling negative minutes is really cool, I'll try to get it working this evening.

Comment: Hi, okay, I got this working to a point. http://paulodonovan.net/Experiments/JavaScript/rise-and-shine/rise-and-shine_0.8.html The problem is it gets to just after the hour, e.g. 18:00 and then adds a new number, i.e. 18:000   Any thoughts? Thanks again! Paul

Comment: You chose the original variable names that I posted, which conflict with a different part of the code - see how it's different in my edit of 23 hours ago

Comment: If you don't want to rename them all, then have `time_wr` as `time_wr = time_min + ":" + time_hours;`, as these are already padded.

Comment: That has fixed it, thanks a mil! http://paulodonovan.net/Experiments/JavaScript/rise-and-shine/rise-and-shine_0.9.html     For a final tweek, I was thinking of playing a small .wav file, e.g. this popping sound plays when the browser loads: http://paulodonovan.net/Experiments/JavaScript/rise-and-shine/playsound_2.html  but I would want to insert it/activate it with the alarm's alert, I don't know is that possible? No worries if I'm asking too much, Thanks this was very useful and fun :)

Comment: You could use an [`<audio>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/audio), via the [`HTMLAudioElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/HTMLAudioElement) _DOM_ interface. Basically, `var wav = new Audio(url_to_file);` (load this in earlier so it doesn't need to wait for buffer) then start with `wav.play();`

Comment: working :) http://paulodonovan.net/Experiments/JavaScript/rise-and-shine/rise-and-shine_1.0.html Danke!

Comment: hmm, I made it 10 mins fast instead of slow, now Firefox doesn't alert

Comment: Did you do the inverse of step 3? And make sure that you're setting a time that won't take 23 hours-something to go off? :P

Comment: Yep, inverted it. I tested it earlier in my language school with FF9 (the slow alarm version worked, but not the fast) but my up-to-date FF has no problem. FF9 is not good for German stuff anyway since it won't output umlauts properly. Re: 23hrs waiting, yes I did that by accident, but I noticed my error thankfully. Perhaps (since I also make music) I have a good sense of time •_•

Answer (score 1):

Add `id` attribute to:  `<select id="hours" name="hours">`

This is how you need to get the value from the hours drop down:

```
var hourField = document.getElementById("hours");
var obj_hours = hourField.options[hourField.selectedIndex].value;
```

You may need to do the same in your `mins` dropdown box too.