# simple php alarm clock how to check constantly if time is reached

Tags: javascript, php

I want to build a simple php alarm clock, where i can set the hours and minutes.

This is what i've got to check for the time:

```
$Minutes = 00;
$Hours = 9;
if (date("H") == $Hours && date("i") >= $Minutes) 
{
echo "RIIIIING";
}
```

How can I ensure that the script keeps querying? So I can leave the document open until the time is reached and it echoes "riiing"

thank you :)

Comment: use ajax with an interval

Comment: why not to do this with javascript on client side?

Comment: Given you have added JavaScript as a tag to your question, This might help you: [**JavaScript Alarmclock Script**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486428/javascript-alarmclock-script) using `setInterval`. Just use your code within the function instead and use the rest of the answer/question to make your check/loop.

Comment: Or you can calculate the difference between now and the alarm time and put the php in sleep($seconds)

Answer (score 2):

You can just put your code into a while statement.But it is better to use JavaScript, because you will eventually get an time out.

```
while(true)
{

 $Minutes = 00;
 $Hours = 9;
 if (date("H") == $Hours && date("i") >= $Minutes) 
 {
    echo "RIIIIING";
 }
}
```

Comment: thanks man. Hm how would i realize this in javascript? I am a beginner :=

Comment: @MarcSter: I don't know about PhP but a `while` loop in JavaScript will block the browser and you only end up seeing the last value instead of an updated value each loop, unless within each loop you have a `setTimeout`.  When doing this in JavaScript a `setInterval` would be better than a `while`. I also already posted a comment on your question linking to another Stackoverflow post which contains enough code showing how you can do this in JavaScript. You should even be able to copy-paste some of it.

Comment: The link you have posted fits my needs perfectly! I just need a way to execute the php inside the js :/ i have searched for that.. but haven't found a good solution yet

Answer (score 1):

You are not going to do this with php.

Best solution with lowest memory & cpu usage in javascript:

```
<script>
   var audio = new Audio('audio_file.mp3');

   var eta_ms = new Date(2015, 0, 21, 17, 0).getTime() - Date.now();

   var timeout = setTimeout(function(){
                    audio.play();
                 }, eta_ms);

</script>
```

Explanation:

1- Inside the new Audio() specify your alarm audio file path.

2- Specify exact date and time that you want to alarm been triggered for new Date parameters.

If you wanted more information feel free to comment this question and ask your questions.